# Why does Windows 10 show ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when in my home network but not when somewhere else?

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, router, dns

**Setup and problem discussion:**

I've set up a laptop in my home running CentOS 7 as a webserver with a virtual host DOMAIN.TLD. I've forwarded ports 80 and 443 to the webserver laptop from my home Comcast router, and I'm using a letsencrypt certificate. I set an external DNS server that I control to point DOMAIN.TLD to my home router's wan IPv4 address.

On another laptop running Linux (Fedora 36), I can go to DOMAIN.TLD in any browser (Chrome, Firefox, Brave) and it invokes the virtual host properly, whether the Linux laptop is in my home network, using the Comcast router wifi, or somewhere else, like, for example, the local library using their wifi.

However, on a laptop running Windows 10, I can get to DOMAIN.TLD only when the Windows 10 laptop is **not** in my home network. It works from the local library using their wifi, but **not** when it's in my home network. When it's in my home network, the connection to DOMAIN.TLD times out in any browser (Chrome, Edge, Firefox), and shows: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

**Attempts to fix the problem on the Windows 10 laptop:**

1. Used a wired connection to the router instead of wifi
2. Flushed the DNS cache
3. Cleared all browsing data
4. Used Google's DNS servers
5. Turned off Windows Defender Firewall (the only firewall on the laptop)

None of these attempts fixed the problem.

Please note that on the Windows 10 laptop in my home network, nslookup in a command prompt shows that it's properly resolving DOMAIN.TLD to my home Comcast router wan IPv4 address, whether I used the Comcast DNS servers or the Google DNS servers.

(I know that I could probably use a proxy server or VPN on the Windows 10 laptop, but I'd rather not do either.)

**Questions:**

Why does Linux work but not Windows 10?

Is there some setting in Windows 10 to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Which Let's Encrypt Root CA signed the certificate?

Comment: I don't know how to determine this.  How could I find out?  However, please note that the Windows 10 laptop works when it's **not** in my home network.

Comment: Do Windows and Linux give the same IPv4 address for DOMAIN.TLD when inside the local network?

Comment: Linux dig:<br />

Comment: Linux dig gives the lan IP address of the webserver laptop.  Windows nslookup gives the router's wan IP address. Both of these done from inside my home network.  Is Windows checking for the router wan IP address and treating it specially?

Comment: I just took the Windows 10 laptop to the library.  On their wifi, nslookup still shows the router's wan IP address, but surfing to DOMAIN.TLD works.